# How to get Coefficients of my own Design Matrix?

Tags: r, least-squares, coefficients

in a assignment, we are to make a spline regression from scratch.

We are supposed to use the truncated power base (TPB). So we applied the terms from the TBF to each data point x so that we get a n x (d+q+1) Design Matrix X (shown in picture).

How can I fit the beta-coefficients to the data?
Since we have our own Design Matrix, we cannot just use `lm()`, right?

Thanks in advance!

I tried implementing my own Least Squared Error Implementation over the past two days and it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.